# How to show Date in StandardTitleBar

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm using StandardTitleBar from Blackberry 6.0

```
            StandardTitleBar myTitleBar = new StandardTitleBar()
            .addIcon("logo.png").addTitle("App Title").addClock()
            .addNotifications().addSignalIndicator();

    myTitleBar.setPropertyValue(
            StandardTitleBar.PROPERTY_BATTERY_VISIBILITY,
            StandardTitleBar.BATTERY_VISIBLE_LOW_OR_CHARGING);

    setTitleBar(myTitleBar);
```

how to add Date to the StandardTitleBar, since it's only have addClock() method, no addDate() method. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want to add the date (i.e. how should it show up?)? You can add it using [Manager#add](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#add%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Field%29) but then you may have to do your own layout. You can also just pass a date along with the title (i.e. addTitle("App Title" + myGetDate())).

There is no built in method in the API to add the date, so if you want a particular placement, then you're going to have to do your own layout. If you don't care for the clock, you can override addClock() and sublayout(). You can call super in sublayout, followed by the code to properly align your date.

Comment: I would recommend the addTitle solution. Messing with the layout isn't going to be all that simple, and it will kind of defeat the purpose of the component, which is to provide a "Standard" functioning title bar across the platform.